# Прописная или строчная буква в прозвищах: всё ли так однозначно и в чём подвох с Человеком-пауком?

Tags: орфография, семантика, прописная-строчная, ономастика

Следую правилу, что все слова в прозвищах (кроме служебных) пишутся с прописной: Геральт — Мясник из Блавикена (из "Ведьмака"), Том Реддл — Лорд Волан-де-Морт, или Тот, Чьё Имя Нельзя Называть (из "Гарри Поттера") и т. д. Но вот в некоторых случаях возникли сомнения.

Почему-то рука не поднимается в прозвищах вроде Вор Долины Мракен или Ужас Деревни Ксардо писать "долины" и "деревни" с прописной. Чаще в тексте употребляется сокращённое прозвище (просто Вор или просто Ужас), и остальная часть воспринимается как какая-то лишняя, или, возможно, дело в том, что к прозвищу стыкуются географические названия с родовыми словами ("долина", "деревня"), которые непривычно писать с прописной.

Так вот, это надуманная проблема из области "нравится — не нравится" и правило прозвищ незыблемо, или и правда есть какие-то особенности, исключения, которые оправдывают в них строчные буквы?

Сомнения посеял тот факт, что в прозвище Питера Паркера, Человек-паук, слово "паук" почему-то пишется со строчной (см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=243541)). А в прозвище, например, Линбоу, Воин-Волк, слово "волк" пишется по правилу — с прописной; это из сериала "Могучие рейнджеры: Мистическая сила" (см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309505)). Почему: Воин-Волк, но Человек-паук? Ведь та же Чёрная Вдова из тех же комиксов Marvel — тоже супергеройское прозвище (Наташи Романовой), как и у Питера Паркера, но пишется-то по правилу (см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=301497))!

Чем это объясняется? С "долиной" и "деревней" тоже так можно? В чём подвох?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила — и при объяснении, почему в прозвище (псевдониме) Человек-паук второе слово пишется со строчной,  ссылается на статью "ПРОПИСНЫЕ И СТРОЧНЫЕ БУКВЫ В СОБСТВЕННЫХ ИМЕНАХ, ПРОЗВИЩАХ, ПСЕВДОНИМАХ, КЛИЧКАХ: ПРОЕКТ АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИХ ПРАВИЛ" (авторы: Е. В. Арутюнова, Е. В. Бешенкова, О. Е. Иванова), в которой описано огромное количество случаев, когда прозвище можно не считать прозвищем или его части можно не писать с прописной (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309621)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что ответ на ваш вопрос хотя бы частично присутствует в материале И.В. Нечаевой [Собственные имена людей (антропонимы)](https://www.ruslang.ru/sites/default/files/doc/ortho/20092021_Nechaeva.pdf)

> **Примечание 1**. Составные имена, в которых вторая часть является не
> индивидуальным прозвищем, а родовым наименованием в форме
> грамматического приложения, обозначающим отношение именуемого к
> определенной категории лиц, пишутся через дефис; вторая нарицательная
> часть пишется со строчной буквы, например: Илья-пророк,
> Марфа-посадница, Николай-угодник.

От себя добавлю, что в прозвище Человек-паук, по этой логике, как раз использовано родовое наименование "паук", ведь Питер Паркер не единственный "человек-паук". Там, как минимум, есть ещё Моралис и три женщины-паука.

> **Примечание 2**. Условные закрепившиеся
> перифрастические прозвища, употребляемые вместо имени или фамилии,
> пишутся обычно с одной прописной в первом слове (и во входящих в прозвище
> собственных именах). Кавычки применяются факультативно. Примеры:
> Буревестник революции (о М. Горьком), Железный Феликс (Дзержинский),
> Железный хромец (Тамерлан), Железная леди (о М. Тэтчер), Желтый
> император (первый император Китая), Орлеанская дева (Жанна д’Арк),
> Тушинский вор (Лжедмитрий II), Русская ракета (о фигуристке
> А.Трусовой) (но: Железная Маска (метонимическое образование –
> наименование целого по его части) пишется с двумя прописными).
> Прозвище «Король-солнце» ~ «король-солнце» (Людовик XIV) пишется
> вариативно – с прописной или со строчной буквы.

Тогда почему Железная леди пишется с одной прописной, а Серебряный Соболь, Чёрная Вдова и Ядовитый Плющ с двумя? Потому что "Железная леди" это описательная конструкция, перифраза. А три остальных случая — это личные псевдонимы.
Собственно, ту же логику вы можете применить к Человеку-пауку. Он не выбирал себе это имя в качестве псевдонима, а так его окрестили газетчики, создав, по сути, перифрастическое прозвище.

Что касается вашего предположения о том, что

> возможно, дело в том, что к прозвищу стыкуются географические названия
> с родовыми словами ("долина", "деревня"), которые непривычно писать с
> прописной,

то я соглашусь с тем, что дело, видимо, в привычке. Нет правила, которое бы говорило, что отдельные категории слов внутри прозвищ должны писаться со строчной (кроме тех, что по ссылке). Прозвище на то и имя собственное, чтобы быть абсолютно любым.

P.S. С интересом бы почитал подобный материал на тему прописных букв в именах легендарных животных (Жеводанский Зверь, Ламбтонский червь, лохнесское чудовище и др.)