# Прописная или строчная буква в составных именах уникального оружия с родовым словом?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика, имена

Пожалуйста, скажите, если в названии (имени) уникального оружия имеется родовое слово, следует ли его писать с прописной буквы или нет? Есть подобные устоявшиеся примеры в литературе?

- меч Вострый (М/м)еч;
- клинок Ультра-(К/к)линок;
- бластер Мега-(Б/б)ластер;
- булава Чёрная (Б/б)улава и пр.

P. S.

"Грамота.ру" при ответе на похожий вопрос  (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471011/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%85-%D1%81)) сослалась на статью "ПРОПИСНЫЕ И СТРОЧНЫЕ БУКВЫ В СОБСТВЕННЫХ ИМЕНАХ, ПРОЗВИЩАХ, ПСЕВДОНИМАХ, КЛИЧКАХ: ПРОЕКТ АКАДЕМИЧЕСКИХ ПРАВИЛ" (авторы: Е. В. Арутюнова, Е. В. Бешенкова, О. Е. Иванова). Возможно, это поможет разобраться сведущим в теме людям (я так понял, что написание вариативно: родовое слово в составе имени можно писать как с прописной, так и со строчной).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила, см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309873).

> Приведенные Вами сочетания неудачны с лексической точки зрения. В области официальных наименований иногда встречаются подобные образования (например, *деревня Новая Деревня*), но распространять эту модель не стоит, родовое слово дублировать в названии не нужно, писать его правильно со строчной буквы: *Вострый меч*, *Чёрная булава*, *Ультраклинок*, *Мегабластер*. Части *мега-* и *ультра-* пишутся слитно.