# Как пишутся имена/прозвища неодушевлённых предметов?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика, названия

У меня довольно комплексный вопрос: хотелось бы узнать, как верно пишутся имена/прозвища конкретных неодушевлённых предметов, всё по правилам написания имён, то есть первое слово и все последующие с прописных, кроме родовых и служебных, или есть нюансы? Приведу разные примеры написания уникальных (существующих в единственном экземпляре) предметов по структуре названия.

1. Когда на первом месте — родовое слово, а на втором — название в именительном падеже, то как правильно? Например: *меч Экскалибур, клинок Рассекатель Зари, щит Всесильный Защитник на Страже Лунного Царства, кольцо Алая Кровь, автомобиль Весёлая Тачанка, телевизор Неработающий Гад* и пр.?
2. А если структура та же, но название употреблено НЕ в именительном падеже? Например: *меч Чернокаменной Крепости, ожерелье Туманов, шлем Эльфов, кольцо Всевластья, болтер Всеиспепеляющего Пламени, сковорода Вечно Пригарающих Котлет, чайник Из Дешёвого Китайского Пластика, ваза С Дурными Узорами* и пр.?
3. А если у нас родовое слово уходит в конец названия? Например: *Вострый меч, Чёрная булава, Убивающая Наповал секира, Всем Надоевший будильник, Адски Исписанная Непонятным Почерком тетрадь* и пр.?

Частично этой темы я касался в другом своём вопросе (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/472750/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)), но не получил убедительных ответов.

Что касается случая 3, тоже задавал схожий вопрос (см. [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/471818/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)), "Грамота.ру" ответила, что верно было бы "Вострый меч" и "Чёрная булава", но насчёт остального не спрашивал и поэтому не уверен.

Comment: Можете спросить у ИРЯ. Они, по идее, гораздо умнее (самый топ), и их не надо 10 раз спрашивать.

Comment: Писать заглавными буквами это транслит и переводы слов на западный манер - capital nouns.